# Correct way to implement JavaFX ObservableValue interface

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Looking for correct way to implement `ObservableBooleanValue` which will be depends of `StringPropertyValue`. For binding with button's `disableProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to implement the interface yourself. You can use [the `createBooleanBinding` method of the `Bindings` utility class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createBooleanBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-):

```
BooleanBinding binding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(new Callable<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        return theStringProperty.get().contains("42");
    }

}, theStringProperty);

someNode.disableProperty().bind(binding);
```

The above code disables `someNode` if `theStringProperty` contains a value with `42` as substring.